# email confirmation using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I follow the instruction in vs code after i run rails g devise:install
I added config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 } in development.rb
I also uncomment the confirmable in migration file .
I also added confirmable in user.rb
In environment.rb this is what i have

```
  # Load the Rails application.
require_relative "application"

# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize!

ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
address: 'smtp.gmail.com',
port: 465,
domain: 'gmail.com',
user_name: ENV['test@gmail.com'],
password: ENV['123456'],
authentication: 'plain',
:ssl =>true,
:tsl => true,
enable_starttls_auto: true

}
```

Im not sure on how to put the correct username and password .
Im not getting any error message when i go to signup but when i go to the email that i use to sign up , im not getting any email .

I also enable less secure app in google settings for both email .

Please help
Thank you

Comment: For development I would really recommend that you use the [mailcatcher gem](https://mailcatcher.me/) instead of actually connecting to Gmail.  Gmail does various anti-spam measures like IP whitelists that make setting it up locally a pain in the arse and then you have to repeat the whole process for production anyways.

Answer (score 1):

The modern Rails approach (5.1+) is to use [encrypted secrets](https://kirillshevch.medium.com/encrypted-secrets-credentials-in-rails-6-rails-5-1-5-2-f470accd62fc). When you run `rails credentials:edit` Rails will open a basic credentials file in your editor of choice. You can then just add your Gmail password and email to the file:

```
gmail:
  password: your_password_goes_here
  user_name: your-email-address@gmail.com
```

Rails will then create the `config/credentials.yml.enc` file that can be checked into version control. The file is encrypted with your `master.key` file which should not be checked into version control.

You can then access the encrypted secrets with `Rails.application.credentials`:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  address: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  port: 465,
  domain: 'gmail.com',
  user_name: Rails.application.credentials.gmail.fetch(:user_name),
  password: Rails.application.credentials.gmail.fetch(:password),
  authentication: 'plain',
  ssl: true,
  tsl: true,
  enable_starttls_auto: true
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly you need to install a gem such as [dotenv-rails](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv).

This will allow you to use environment variables.

To do so create a `.env` file in the root of your project.

Inside of that file you can add environment variables such as:

```
EMAIL_USERNAME=someusername
EMAIL_PASSWORD=somepassword
```

And then in your `environment.rb` you can use it like this:

```rb
user_name: ENV['EMAIL_USERNAME'],
password: ENV['EMAIL_PASSWORD']
```

Comment: Is there anyway I can simply put my username and pw without install gems ??
like username: 'test@gmail.com'
password: '123456'

Comment: Yeah, just use it without the environment variables. Just put ex. `user_name: "someusername@mail.com"`

Comment: But it is safer with environment variables, because you can just not check it into Git and it will keep your credentials secure.

Comment: This is a highly outdated approach. Use encrypted secrets instead. If you really want to set ENV vars from a file use shellenv or any of the other the modern language agnositic tools instead of putting dotenv in your gemfile.

Comment: @max Thanks for your input. Your answer is better and more secure.